# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error in node save

Tags: nodes, forms

I built a custom form and one of them is of  type geocode with lat/lon fields. When I try to save the node I receive the following error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/modules/field/field.attach.inc on
>   line 208\n'.

The error disappears when I put comments in this field. My question is how can I solve this since it is very important field (I try to create nodes with geocode locations)

Here is how I declare my field:

```
$form['field_locationmap'] = array(
    '#title' => 'geofield',
    '#type' => 'geofield_latlon',
  );
```

It seems that the error occurs when I m trying to pass the values to the object:

```
$location->field_locationmap->und->{0}->geom->lon=$form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lon'];
$location->field_locationmap->und->{0}->geom->lat=$form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lat'];
```

Comment: is this drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: @kombogdan The placement of Field Module in drupal-root/modules says it is drupal 7 not 8 or above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Drupal 7 field_locationmap is an array so your assignment should look something like this:

```
$location->field_locationmap['und'][0]['geom']['lat']
```

Also make sure that['geom']['lat'] is the correct structure for that value (i.e it is an array with two keys)
P.S. Consider using $location->language instead of 'und' in case you support multiple languages.

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite. The error is _Cannot use object of type stdClass as array_, which means the code is using an object as array. It's not even the code shown in the question, to cause the error, but Drupal core code (modules/field/field.attach.inc).

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the error. if you first create a stdClass like so: $obj->prop and then some other place you will try to do $obj['prop'] you will get that error. 
The error happens while trying to store the node to database. Thus the error within Drupal core. Look into entities and fielding process within Drupal 7 for better understanding of the process.

Comment: But the OP is showing a line like `$location->field_locationmap->und->{0}->geom->lon`, which cannot be causing the _cannot use object of type stdClass as array_ error, since the code would eventually use an array as object, and you are suggesting to use `$location->field_locationmap['und'][0]['geom']['lat']`.

Comment: The error is clear enough: The code causing it is using as array an object. That is not the case of the code shown from the OP, which is using the operator to access object properties.

Comment: `$var = new stdClass(); echo $var[0];` throws a _Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array_ error, but `$var = ["a" => 0, "b" => 2]; echo $var->a;` throws a _PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'a' of non-object_ message. So, it's clear which is the OP's case. The error is not even caused from the code the OP is showing, since the error message clearly states the error is caused from code in modules/field/field.attach.inc (line 208).

Comment: Not sure what are you referring to or what is your specific issue with my answer. But here is an excerpt from the mentioned module (btw its in free access out in the internet so next time consider looking it up):
foreach ($languages as $langcode) {
        $items = isset($entity->{$field_name}[$langcode]) ? $entity->{$field_name}[$langcode] : array();
Thus OP doing something like $location->field_locationmap->und with cause en error.

Comment: The answer is wrong since it is suggesting to change the wrong part of the code.

Comment: Could you elaborate how changing $location->field_locationmap->und to $location->field_locationmap['und'] is wrong? Considering of course the source for the field module.

Comment: It's wrong because it's not that the line causing the error. The OP should show more of the used code, and maybe we could answer that.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but still believe that even if the code posted is not the exact reason of the error understanding the difference between array and ctdClass in context of Drupal is very important. If OP provides feedback and this is not helpful please feel free to remove the answer.

Comment: We don't remove answers just because they are wrong answers. You didn't even write a comment as answer, so there isn't any reason to remove it.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your support. I apologize for my late response due to personal issue.. Concerning the issue,  I m almost certain that this is causing it (or at least this with the combination of drupal core) because when I comment them the node is saved without issues. Is there any way to change these lines since I suppose it is difficult and not correct  to change the core file of drupal 7? Thanks for your help..

Comment: As i suggested in the answer try to change everything past the field_locationmap to arrays (i.e. $location->field_locationmap['und'][0]['geom']['lat'])

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [Entity metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers) solution to set values of an entity (in this case node) , if so you have to use `set` method like this :

`$location->field_locationmap->set([$form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lon'], $form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lat']]);`

if not using entity metadata wrapper you might using some code like below:

```
$location = new stdClass();
$location->field_locationmap->und->{0}->geom->lon=$form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lon'];
$location->field_locationmap->und->{0}->geom->lat=$form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lat'];
$location->save();
```

if so as drupal expects fields value to be an array, it throws exception when facing object, so you need to modify your code like this:

```
$location = new stdClass();
$location->field_locationmap['und'][0]['geom'] = [
  'lon' => $form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lon'],
  'lat' => $form_state['values']['field_locationmap']['lat']
];
$location->save();
```